# Core Text on Retina Macs

Tags: macos, retina-display, core-text

I use Core Text to draw text to an offscreen bitmap context using `CTLineDraw()`. The bitmap is then processed internally before it is drawn to my window.

The problem here is that bitmap contexts aren't scaled on Retina Macs. Thus, on a Retina Mac, the text is still drawn at 72dpi to the bitmap but it should be drawn in 144dpi of course, because the pixel density is twice as high. Thus, the text currently looks blurry because it is drawn at 72dpi to the offscreen bitmap and this bitmap is then scaled when it is drawn to the window.

What is the best way to make Core Text Retina-aware in this context? Should I simply pass a transformation matrix to `CTFontCreateWithName()` that contains the screen's `backingScaleFactor` in its scale coefficients? That does look a little hackish, though. That's why I'm asking for some feedback or a better idea...

Comment: I saw a related question a few days ago. Maybe the solution is there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002222/using-core-text-on-mac-book-pro-hd-screen-different-text-sizes ?

Comment: Looks like a different problem because he doesn't draw to an offscreen bitmap first. There wouldn't be any problems on Retina Macs if I didn't draw to an offscreen bitmap. The problem is that offscreen bitmaps aren't scaled so I need to manually find a solution to adapt my code for Retina Macs. And the question is what is the best way to do so...